# Concatenating strings with different separators depending on the number of occurrences

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)

names <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~number,
  1, "232",
  2, "321",
  3, "473", 
  2, "367",
  3, "643",
  3, "565",
  3, "214",
)
```

I am writing an R Markdown document with a corresponding function that loops over the data frame and creates a report for each unique `id` in the data frame (in this case, 3 reports). In each report, I am looking to reference all instances in the `number` column for each unique `id`. I am thus looking for something to concatenate the strings in the `number` column. My end-goal is the below data frame:

```r
names_expected <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~number, ~numbers,
  1, "232", "232",
  2, "321", "321 and 367",
  3, "473", "473, 643, 565 and 214", 
  2, "367", "321 and 367",
  3, "643", "473, 643, 565 and 214",
  3, "565", "473, 643, 565 and 214",
  3, "214", "473, 643, 565 and 214"
)
```

Problems:

- How do I mutate the `numbers` column such that the `numbers` column concatenates all `number`s occuring for an `id`, i.e. the mutated column for the first occurrence where `id == 2` should be `"321 and 367"` and not `"321 and 321"`.
- The separators in the concatenated string will differ depending on the number of strings that are concatenated:

1. No separator is needed when the number of occurrences of the `id` is 1.
2. When an `id` occurs twice the separator should be `" and "`.
3. When an `id` occurs more than twice, the separator for the first `n-1` occurrences should be `", "` and `" and "` for the last occurrence.

Ideally looking for a `{dplyr}` solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

names %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(numbers = toString(number), numbers = ifelse(n() == 1, numbers, str_replace(numbers, ',(\\s)(\\d+$)', '\\1and \\2')))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
     id number numbers              
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>                
1     1 232    232                  
2     2 321    321 and 367          
3     3 473    473, 643, 565 and 214
4     2 367    321 and 367          
5     3 643    473, 643, 565 and 214
6     3 565    473, 643, 565 and 214
7     3 214    473, 643, 565 and 214
```

Comment: It does - thanks! However, your code adds a `","` before the `"and"`, e.g. `"473, 643, 565, and 214"`. Is it possible to  adapt the regex to have it become `"473, 643, 565 and 214"` instead?

Comment: @RikardWahlström, I noticed and changed that already